# Created alias exists only during the session and is gone after logging out

Tags: unix, alias, putty, cd

I connected to my unix account using putty. Then I created an alias as - 
alias go 'cd/some big path'

This alias then worked in the session. 
But after logging out and again logging in, I found that the alias was gone!!!

Any way to make alias permanent.

Answer (score 2):

Put the aliases in your `~/.bashrc` file - *i.e.* inside the file named `.bashrc` in your home directory. This directory located at: `$HOME`, `/home/user` or something similar. If you `cd` with no arguments you will be in your home directory.

Comment: Am very new to unix. Can't find .bashrc file. Should I create it and put the alias command inside it?

Comment: go to your home directory and do
    ls -la ~/ | more
if the file is there, it shoud be on the first page, if not, create ist with
    vi ~/.bashrc

Comment: There is no option for this command to store it in this file? Is it necessary to write it manually to .bashrc?